# Pandas: copy structure and set all elements

Tags: python, pandas

Having a pandas object, say "pdObj1", with a certain structure (i.e. column names, row indices, etc.), I would like to create a "pdObj2" with the same structure but different content.

What is the fastest (lines of code OR execution speed) way to do this? Currently I am using:

```
pdObj2 = pdObj1.copy()
pdObj2[:] = 0
```

As I am doing this quite often I wanted to check this is optimal.

---

### Timing of Caroline Alexiou's suggestion

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = """\
... import pandas as pd
... a = pd.Series(range(int(1e6)))
... """
... 
>>> s1 = """\
... b = a.copy()
... b[:] = 0"""
... 
>>> s2 = """b = pd.Series(index=a.index).fillna(0)"""
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s1, setup=setup, number=100)
3.292705357803854
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s2, setup=setup, number=100)
140.00138844462077
```

---

### Timing of DSM's suggestion

Setting up the the problem:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.Series(range(int(1e6)))
```

Copying structure and setting all elements to new value:

```
In [3]: %timeit b=a.copy(); b[:]=0
10 loops, best of 3: 33.3 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit b=pd.Series(0, index=a.index)
100 loops, best of 3: 34 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit b=pd.Series(index=a.index).fillna(0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop
```

Copying structure and setting single element to new value:

```
In [6]: %timeit b=a.copy(); b[:]=0; b[500000] = 1
10 loops, best of 3: 40.2 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit b=pd.Series(0, index=a.index); b[500000]=1
100 loops, best of 3: 34.7 ms per loop
```

Timings carried out on:

```
In [8]: import sys

In [9]: print (sys.version)
2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (32-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:50:31) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `0` as the data argument, i.e. `pd.Series(0, index=a.index)`:

```
>>> a = pd.Series(range(int(1e6)))
>>> %timeit b=pd.Series(index=a.index).fillna(0)
1 loops, best of 3: 409 ms per loop
>>> %timeit b=a.copy(); b[:] = 0
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop
>>> %timeit b=pd.Series(0, index=a.index)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. On my machine both solutions have the same execution speed. A slight edge for b=a.copy(), b[:]=0 but more surprisingly, when first setting all values to zero and then a single to a new value a variant of your solution is a good bit faster. (See my ammended question for an illustration.) - Very odd.

Comment: There might also be some version dependence; I use bleeding-edge pandas, and so if anything's changed recently you might not be picking that up if you're using whatever's current in anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
 newdf = pd.DataFrame(index=prevdf.index,columns=prevdf.columns).fillna(0)
```

This just copies the structure (index and columns) without copying all the values and then overwriting them, so it may be faster.

Comment: Thanks. Your reasoning was very convincing. I gave it a whirl with the timeit module and the pd.Series object and found much to my surprise that your suggestion is significantly slower. I have a feeling that some initialisation step is avoided with my (naive) approach... Any insights?

Comment: Hm, seems like this fillna is not suitable then... It probably checks each element for null before making it zero (which makes sense)... but this means that it is not a bulk operation. Still, the time difference is huge - I wonder if it's even vectorized..